# Ошибка ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение при использовании requests_html render

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я использую `requests_html` для отрисовки элементов javascript.
Эта ошибка возникает на любом сайте.

Код:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('URL')
r.html.render()  # Если закомментировать ошибки не будет
body = r.html.find('#target-dummydiv', first=True)
print(body.text)
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
```

Comment: могли бы добавить ссылку на один из сайтов, который пытаетесь использовать и с которым происходит данная ошибка

Comment: @MaximChyorny сайт: https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/ru/Text

Comment: передавайте заголовки, которые передаются при отправке запроса для перевода на сайт и тогда ошибки не будет, однако вам это не поможет получить Готовый перевод

Comment: @MaximChyorny спасибо, ошибка ушла. Не подскажете почему перевод не появился?

Comment: перевод подгружается за счет отправки первого запроса с адресом https://www2.deepl.com/jsonrpc?method=LMT_handle_jobs и некоторым словарем json с данными, после в отклик вы получите другой словарь в json формате, там и будет перевод вашего текста либо слова, однако перевод мне удалось получить после отправки запроса в rest client, не в python - не знаю почему так

Answer (score 1):

Вы пользовались render() раньше?

> Note, the first time you ever run the render() method, it will
> download Chromium into your home directory (e.g. ~/.pyppeteer/). This
> only happens once. You may also need to install a few Linux packages
> to get pyppeteer working.

Если с другими сайтами работает, возможно на этом сайте есть элемент, который не грузится.
Откройте в браузере и посмотрите в Инструментах разработчика, в консоли или или в Сети, нет ли ошибок на сайте.

Comment: Раньше не пользовался. Хромиум скачался.
Я попробовал сайты Гугла и Яндекса. Гугл прошёл без ошибок, Яндекс с ошибкой.